# How to manage Kubernetes secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, configmap, kubernetes-secrets

Can anyone suggest me How I manage my Kubernetes secrets? till now I used to use kubectl or Helm to apply secrets from my local system but this is not the right way to do I guess. I also refer few docs about managing Kubernetes secrets, from that some are mention below,

> I find hashicorp vault which is also used to manage secrets https://www.vaultproject.io/use-cases/kubernetes

> Aws secret https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/

but still, I m looking for the other available option to manage secrets. Please suggest me the best and most secure way to store and manage secrets in Kubernetes. for your kind information I m using AWS EKS cluster so please help me out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74228996/how-to-use-kubernetes-secret-to-pull-a-private-docker-image-from-docker-hub Does this answer your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70618016/5525824